# how to use a common service for different json data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I created a service that fetches data from local json and use it in a controller to display it in browser. All are working fine. here is my code:

JS Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

myApp.service("dataService", function($http, $q){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.get('json/link.json').then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

   this.getData = function(){
     return deferred.promise;
   }
})
.controller("linkCtrl", function($scope, dataService) {
    var promise = dataService.getData();
    promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.links = data.data;
    });
});
```

Now, i have another json link (for eg.: json/link2.json ) and i want to perform the same function. Is there any way to use the "dataService" service ( like changing the link ).

I don't want to re-create a new service which does the same function. Any idea to re-use the Service for different json data ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried passing the URL to the service?

Comment: Do you need to cache the promise?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method you can pass url to:

```
myApp.service("dataService", function($http){
   this.getData = function(url){
      return $http.get(url); // this returns a promise
   };
})
```

Use it like this:

```
.controller("linkCtrl", function($scope, dataService) {
    var promise1 = dataService.getData('json/link.json');
    promise1.then(function(data) {
        $scope.links = data.data;
    });

    var promise2 = dataService.getData('json/link2.json');
    promise2.then(function(data) {
        $scope.links2 = data.data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
myApp.service("dataService", function($http){
 this.getData = function(link,callback){
 $http.get(link).then(function(data){
    if(callback)
      callback(data);
   });
});
myApp.controller("linkCtrl", function($scope, dataService) {
    dataService.getData('json/link.json', function(data){
      $scope.links = data.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain the service function used here?

Comment: i defined service function with a callback function and a link param. after http.get returns some thing from link we provided we check callback funciton. if it exists we call it with data. on controller we are calling getData function of service with link and a function and we say that function expects a parameter. now callback = function(data) etc... and service used that callback function now that data value is comes from service